How to build the "Receiving a notification any time the selection changes in an Explorer window" program by the Visual Studio Community Edition 2015?
When building this "Little Program" source:
#define STRICT
#include <windows.h>
#include <ole2.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <shdispid.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <stdio.h>
class CShellFolderViewEventsSink :
    public CDispInterfaceBase<DShellFolderViewEvents>
{
public:
 CShellFolderViewEventsSink() { }
 HRESULT SimpleInvoke(
    DISPID dispid, DISPPARAMS *pdispparams, VARIANT *pvarResult)
 {
  switch (dispid) {
  case DISPID_SELECTIONCHANGED:
   printf("Selection changed!\n");
   break;
  }
  return S_OK;
 }
};
int __cdecl wmain(int, wchar_t **)
{
 CCoInitialize init;
 CComPtr<IShellFolderViewDual> spFolderView;
 GetDesktopAutomationObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&spFolderView));
 CComPtr<CShellFolderViewEventsSink> spSink;
 spSink.Attach(new CShellFolderViewEventsSink());
 spSink->Connect(spFolderView);
 MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Click OK when bored."), TEXT("Title"), MB_OK);
 spSink->Disconnect();
 return 0;
}

(origin came from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140922-00/?p=44013)
by the "Build Solution (Ctrl+Shift+B)" it will end with many errors:
Severity    Code    Description                     Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      CDispInterfaceBase is not a template    ATLProject1PS   Source.cpp  9
Error (active)      identifier "CCoInitialize" is undefined ATLProject1PS   Source.cpp  26
Error (active)      identifier "GetDesktopAutomationObject" is undefined    ATLProject1PS   Source.cpp  28
Error (active)      class "ATL::_NoAddRefReleaseOnCComPtr<CShellFolderViewEventsSink>" has no member "Connect"   ATLProject1PS   Source.cpp  31
Error (active)      class "ATL::_NoAddRefReleaseOnCComPtr<CShellFolderViewEventsSink>" has no member "Disconnect"    ATLProject1PS   Source.cpp  33
... etc.
Please what "New Project" type (C++ ATL or other) should be created to successfully build this source code?
Created new project by the menu File / New / Project..., added source file and build:
1. New Project / Installed / Templates / Visual C++ / Windows / ATL / ATL Project
2. Solution Explorer / Source Files / Add / New Item / C++ File (Name: Source.cpp)
3. Build / Build Solution (Ctrl+Shift+B)
